# Аналог битового поля на C#

Tags: c#, c++

Есть следующий код на C++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

union
{
    unsigned short X;
    struct
    {  
        unsigned short param_01 :1; // DSL (младший бит числа X)
        unsigned short param_02 :1; // PPP
        unsigned short param_03 :1; // Link
        unsigned short param_04 :2; // битовое поле может содержать
        unsigned short param_05 :5; // более 1 бита
        unsigned short param_06 :1;
        unsigned short param_07 :1;
        unsigned short param_08 :2;
    } X_bit;
} Device;

int main()
{
    cin >> hex >> Device.X; // вводим число

    // Выводим результаты
    cout << Device.X_bit.param_01;
    cout << Device.X_bit.param_02;
    // и так далее

    return 0;
 }
```

Каким образом получить аналогичную функциональность на C#? Есть ли там битовые поля, а если нету, как лучше работать с такими данными?

Comment: ruSO это не сайт для переводов.

Comment: Учите битовые операции. Они вам понадобятся, так как прямого аналога упакованным структурам в C# нет.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что тут не бюро переводов

Comment: Для начала, ваш код не является правильным C++-кодом, т. к. вы обращаетесь не к тому члену union, который присваивали.

Comment: Ну ладно вам закрывать, вопрос нетривиальный. Плохо сформулирован, да.

Comment: @VladD однако, магия эта широко распространенная и без оптимизации вполне работоспособная

Comment: @AndrewBystrov сайт для переводов это meta.ruSO. Для переводов с английского интерфейса на русский :)

Comment: @alexolut: Уже нет.

Comment: Аналог есть смотрите описание на *System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout*.

Comment: @nick_n_a: Это не совсем аналог, в вопросе _битовые_ поля.

Comment: @nick_n_a нету. Там смещения с точностью до байта - а надо до бита.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов В данном случае человек *не просит перевести код*, это вполне корректный вопрос!

Comment: @AndrewBystrov В данном случае человек не просит перевести код, это вполне корректный вопрос о том, как выразить определенную функциональность на языке C#.

Comment: @Harry посмотрите, пожалуйста, изначальный вопрос. По истории правки. Там человек четко написал - помогите перевести с с++ на с# ( линк на историю правки http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/585389/revisions)

Comment: @VladD кстати, нет никакой гарантии, что внутри `union` битовые поля лягут ожидаемым образом на поле `X`. Всё это `implementation-defined`.

Comment: @alexolut: Кстати, да. Но воспроизвести implementation-defined behavior на C# у меня не получится :)

Comment: @ffff, если ответ Вас устраивает - пометьте его как правильный.

Answer (score 6):

Для вашего случая можно воспользоваться структурой [`BitVector32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asbhstzz(v=vs.110).aspx).

Для удобства, положим вот такой вспомогательный класс:

```
class SectionHelper
{
    BitVector32.Section? currSection = null;
    public BitVector32.Section AllocatedSection(int nbits)
    {
        // проверка
        if (nbits <= 0 || nbits > sizeof(short) * 8 - 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("wrong number of bits");
        var max = checked((short)((1 << nbits) - 1));
        currSection = currSection == null ?
                BitVector32.CreateSection(max) :
                BitVector32.CreateSection(max, currSection.Value);
        return currSection.Value;
    }
}
```

Пробуем:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // определяем битовые маски
        SectionHelper helper = new SectionHelper();

        var dsl_s      = helper.AllocatedSection(1);
        var ppp_s      = helper.AllocatedSection(1);
        var link_s     = helper.AllocatedSection(1);
        var param_04_s = helper.AllocatedSection(2);
        var param_05_s = helper.AllocatedSection(5);
        var param_06_s = helper.AllocatedSection(1);
        var param_07_s = helper.AllocatedSection(1);
        var param_08_s = helper.AllocatedSection(2);

        // пользуемся
        var bv = new BitVector32(0x341a);
        Console.WriteLine(bv[dsl_s]);
        Console.WriteLine(bv[ppp_s]);
        Console.WriteLine(bv[link_s]);
        Console.WriteLine(bv[param_04_s]);
        Console.WriteLine(bv[param_05_s]);
        Console.WriteLine(bv[param_06_s]);
        Console.WriteLine(bv[param_07_s]);
        Console.WriteLine(bv[param_08_s]);
        Console.WriteLine();

        bv = new BitVector32(0xcbe5);
        Console.WriteLine(bv[dsl_s]);
        Console.WriteLine(bv[ppp_s]);
        Console.WriteLine(bv[link_s]);
        Console.WriteLine(bv[param_04_s]);
        Console.WriteLine(bv[param_05_s]);
        Console.WriteLine(bv[param_06_s]);
        Console.WriteLine(bv[param_07_s]);
        Console.WriteLine(bv[param_08_s]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если не затруднит, не могли бы Вы дать комментарий по коду, основной вопрос - зачем это нужно и почему не воспользоваться BitArray, даже не в контексте данного вопроса а вообще, зачем подтягивать структуру из, по-моему, 32 бит?

Comment: BitArray — это массив бит, в нём есть удобный доступ к отдельным битам, но нету удобного доступа к полям размером больше одного бита. А проблем с 32-битной структурой я не вижу.