# Чтение и запись битового поля из\в бинарный файл в C#

Tags: c#, c++

Всем доброго времени суток, помогите разобраться как прочитать битовое поле из бинарного файла ? 
Есть структура написанная на C++ Builder :

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int nr:8;   //
    unsigned int y:8;    // 1
    unsigned int sm:3;   // 2
    unsigned int d:5;    // 3
    unsigned int m:4;    // 4
    unsigned int r:4;    // 5
} n_def;
```

как я понял мне для начала нужно прочитать весь блок а затем разбить его на биты ?

```
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open)))
            {
                // пока не достигнут конец файла
                // считываем каждое значение из файла
                while (reader.PeekChar() > -1)
                {
                    int numb = reader.ReadInt32();
                    uint nr = reader.ReadUInt32(); // переменная которую нужно разбить на биты 
   }
}
```

на втором поле `nr` я уже получаю не то что нужно. Как правильнее реализовать задачу ? может лучше использовать другой способ чтения и записи в бинарный файл ? Спасибо за ваши ответы

Продолжение темы : 
[Бинарный файл](http://dropmefiles.com/YwIf6)
 ,простите что выкладываю на обменник просто файл содержит данные с 2004г.

[image: C++ Builder]

А в VS данные такие : 
**nr = 1**

**y = 16 (совпало)**

**sm = 2**

**ds = 15**

**ms = 11**

**rs = 0**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По идее, имеет смысл воспользоваться классом `BitVector32`. Возьмите вспомогательный класс `SectionHelper` [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/585406/10105).

Вам нужно подготовить описание:

```
SectionHelper helper = new SectionHelper();

var nr_s = helper.AllocatedSection(8);
var y_s  = helper.AllocatedSection(8);
var sm_s = helper.AllocatedSection(3);
var d_s  = helper.AllocatedSection(5);
var m_s  = helper.AllocatedSection(4);
var r_s  = helper.AllocatedSection(4);
```

Теперь можно пользоваться.

```
Int32 ndef = reader.ReadInt32();
BitVector32 bv = new BitVector32(ndef);
int nr = bv[nr_s];
int y = bv[y_s];
int sm = bv[sm_s];
// ...
```

На запись:

```
BitVector32 bv = new BitVector32(ndef);
bv[nr_s] = nr;
bv[y_s] = y;
bv[sm_s] = sm;
// ...
Int32 ndef = bv.Data;
// и записываете ndef куда надо
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо, а на запись, точно также все будет выглядеть ?

Comment: @Ethernets: Пожалуйста! Дописал ответ.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо

Comment: @Ethernets: Пожалуйста!

Comment: вы меня извините, но я обнаружил несовпадение данных между тем что есть на С++ и тем что я написал по вашему примеру, у меня совпало только 1 число под переменной `y` не может ли это быть связано из-за несовпадения типов ? в моем вопросе в С++ используется тип  unsigned int а в вашем int, это ведь не одно и тоже, либо я чего-то не понимаю ? помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Спасибо

Comment: @Ethernets: А можно посмотреть в файл хекс-редактором? Чтобы точно понять, в какой точке проблема.

Comment: То есть смотрите, что нужно: (1) какие значения полей в C++? (2) содержимое файла в хекс-редакторе. Имея это, можно порасследовать.

Comment: Сейчас сделаю. Спасибо за быстрый ответ

Comment: Добавил все что нужно

Comment: @Ethernets: Ну, непонятно, что у вас в бинарном файле. У вас на скриншоте какая-то структура `nrt` неизвестного типа с полем `nn`, и непонятно, каким байтам в 400-килобайтном файле это соответствует.

Comment: @Ethernets: Давайте предположим, что у вас генерируются (записываются в файл) две штуки int32 в С++. Вы можете тогда вместо ссылки на файл дать просто значения этих `int32`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50973/discussion-between-ethernets-and-vladd).