# Указание размера битового поля структуры

Tags: c#, struct

Для удобства работы с числами типа [System.Double](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double?view=netframework-4.7.2) (`float64`) мне бы хотелось описать подобную структуру:

```
// cpp code
union float64
{
    double x;
    struct
    {
        unsigned long long mant : 52;
        unsigned long long exp  : 11;
        unsigned long long sign : 1;
    };

    float64(double val) { x = val; }
};

float64 f = -4.0;
// f.mant == 0
// f.exp == 1025 (- 1023 == 2)
// f.sign == 1
```

Иными словами, мне нужна *подноготная* числа с плавающей точкой, описанная стандартом [IEC 60559:1989 (IEEE 754)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#IEC_60559), в быстром, так сказать, доступе

На `C++` это очень легко выразить, оперируя [битовыми полями](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ewwyfdbe.aspx). Однако как сделать подобное на `C#` (элегантно), я придумать не смог: использование [MarshalAsAttribute.SizeConst](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.sizeconst?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) валидно лишь для строк и массивов

Так что единственный вариант, который я пока что вижу, - использование `fixed`-полей, из которых потом и будет грузиться нужное мне число. Но данное решение видится мне немного громоздким...

---

**Можно ли** средствами C# указать определенный размер битового поля, и, если *да*, то **как** сие сделать?

Comment: Ассоциация - [вариант с BitVector32 от @VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585389/%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c). Однако этот метод мне не совсем подходит, ибо у меня 64-битная структура. Да и может с тех пор уже появилось что поэлегантнее)

Comment: Помню, у Скита была глава, посвященная представлению `double`. Там он использовал  `BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits` и маски для получения нужных бит. Элегантно, но порождает некоторые действия, которых в том же примере на `C++` мы избегаем...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://ideone.com/wGW2qq

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct Float64
{
  public Float64(double x) { ULong = 0; Double = x; }
  public static implicit operator Float64(double x) { return new Float64(x); }
  public static implicit operator double(Float64 x) { return x.Double; }

  [FieldOffset(0)] public double Double;
  [FieldOffset(0)] public ulong  ULong;

  public ulong Mantissa
  {
    get { return ULong & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF; }
    set { ULong = ULong & ~0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL | value & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL; }
  }

  public uint Exp
  {
    get { return (uint)((ULong >> 52) & 0x7FF); }
    set { ULong = ULong & 0x800FFFFFFFFFFFFFULL | ((ulong)(value & 0x7FF) << 52); }
  }

  public uint Sign
  {
    get { return (uint)(ULong >> 63); }
    set { ULong = ULong & 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL | ((ulong)value << 63); }
  }
}

public class Test
{
  private static void Print(Float64 x)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0,7} {1:X16} s={4} m={2:X13} e={3:X3}", x.Double, x.ULong, x.Mantissa, x.Exp, x.Sign);
  }

  public static void Main()
  {
    foreach (var d in new double [] { 0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,3.25,-3.25 })
      Print(d);

    Float64 x = 1;
    Print(x);
    ++x.Exp; Print(x); // 2
    x.Sign = 1; Print(x); // -2
    x.Mantissa += 1ULL << 51; Print(x); // -3
    --x.Exp; Print(x); // -1.5
  }
}
```

```
      0 0000000000000000 s=0 m=0000000000000 e=000
      1 3FF0000000000000 s=0 m=0000000000000 e=3FF
     -1 BFF0000000000000 s=1 m=0000000000000 e=3FF
      2 4000000000000000 s=0 m=0000000000000 e=400
     -2 C000000000000000 s=1 m=0000000000000 e=400
      3 4008000000000000 s=0 m=8000000000000 e=400
     -3 C008000000000000 s=1 m=8000000000000 e=400
   3.25 400A000000000000 s=0 m=A000000000000 e=400
  -3.25 C00A000000000000 s=1 m=A000000000000 e=400
      1 3FF0000000000000 s=0 m=0000000000000 e=3FF
      2 4000000000000000 s=0 m=0000000000000 e=400
     -2 C000000000000000 s=1 m=0000000000000 e=400
     -3 C008000000000000 s=1 m=8000000000000 e=400
   -1.5 BFF8000000000000 s=1 m=8000000000000 e=3FF
```

Comment: Благодарю покорно) Добавьте ещё в ответ информацию о том, что `С#` все же не даёт возможности работать с полями, чей размер не кратен размеру одного байта, так что придётся изворачиваться ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ И ещё раз спасибо большое за помощь)

Comment: Не понял про кратность байту. У меня геттеры с сеттерами же как раз некратные сдвиги выставляют.

Comment: А что такое `ULL` на конце шестнадцатеричных чисел?

Comment: Сдвиги - одно дело. Битовые поля в `С++` реально занимают указанное число бит, которое не обязательно должно быть кратно целому числу байт (как то 52, 11 и 1 в моем примере). Вы же в своём примере, манипулируя масками и сдвигами, лишь имитируете подобное поведение, работая все с теми же полями, занимающими целое число байт)

Comment: @АндрейNOP, эм.. Когда я писал, то имел в виду `unsigned long long` и шарп меня понял. Но вообще-то, наверное, должно быть на одну `L` поменьше.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, битовые поля в си и плюсах работают точно так же. Компилятор сам подставляет сдвиги, а поля не могут пересекать границу типа, с которым они объявлены. И пачка подряд идущих полей объединяются в одно по принципу "пока лезут в указанный тип".

Comment: Стандартный компилятор `C# 7.3` не понял, так что да, на одну `L` должно быть меньше)

Comment: Ага, специально пришлось в документацию ходить, но так ничего и не нашёл.

Comment: А, все, я понял. Я просто думал, в плюсах есть какой-то хитрый механизм, дабы отводить под поля нецелое число байтов. А это оказалось просто синтаксическим (условно) сахаром для того, что сейчас проделали Вы на шарпах... Спасибо)

Answer (score 6):

Ещё один вариант, позволяющий обходиться без небезопасного `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]`, такой:

```
struct Float64
{
    public Float64(double x) { Double = x; }
    public static implicit operator Float64(double x) { return new Float64(x); }
    public static implicit operator double(Float64 x) { return x.Double; }

    public double Double;
    public ulong ULong
    {
        get => (ulong)BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(Double);
        set => Double = BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble((long)value);
    }

    ...
}
```

Остальной код как в ответе @Qwertiy.

Comment: О, как я и писал в комментариях) А почему `Explicit` небезопасен? Его поведение ведь полностью документировано ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: А битконвертер с производительностью как дружит? Кстати, я правильно понимаю, что под небезопасностью подразумевается возможность накосячить при выставлении сдвигов, или есть ещё что-то?

Comment: @Qwertiy, меня вот тоже данный вопрос интересует) А битконвертер я сейчас протестирую)

Comment: @Qwertiy, производительность на уровне. Почти не упала) Небольшая разница видна лишь при сотнях тысяч операций

Comment: @VladD - немного не по теме, но https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/887136/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy, **VladD** уже отвечал на этот вопрос году так в 17-ом. Сейчас поищу

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, действительно... Я нашёл :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, у **VladD** в профиле есть ответы практически на все вопросы, которые только можно вообразить хД

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: Небезопасен в основном потому, что можно не угадать с размерами типов и смещениями, и компилятор ничего не скажет.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Я бы ожидал, что хороший JIT-компилятор его заинлайнит. А внутри он делает, понятно, то же самое: `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: Вы меня захваливаете :)

Comment: @VladD, а ну в этом плане да) Но мы же знаем, что делаем, а по сему все нормально)

Comment: @VladD: ну, почему же сразу «захваливаю»? Я ведь когда говорил, что по Вашему профилю целую книгу написать можно, я же не шутил ни капли хД Верите-нет, но изучение `C#` я начал именно благодаря Вашим постам на ruSO. Так что своим знанием данного языка и платформы `.NET` я фактически в нулевую очередь обязан именно Вам, а уже потом спец.литературе. За все время, что Вы провели здесь и на хэшкоде, Вы проделали просто огромную работу, которая действительно помогает людям...) Так что от всей души выражаю Вам благодарность за все Ваши труды!)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: Огромное спасибо! (_Покраснел_)

Comment: @VladD: мне-то как раз не за что говорить спасибо)