# Зачем инициализировать все поля структуры?

Tags: c#, language-lawyer, дизайн-языка

Почему конструктор структуры должен инициализировать все поля, а конструктор класса - нет?

https://ideone.com/1F1BR3

```
using System;

class SmthClass
{
  public int X;
  public int Y;

  public SmthClass(int y) { Y = y; }
}

struct SmthStruct
{
  public int X;
  public int Y;

  public SmthStruct(int y) { Y = y; }
}

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
  }
}
```

> prog.cs(16,28): error CS0171: Field `SmthStruct.X' must be fully assigned before control leaves the constructor

Comment: Вы не обидитесь, если я помечу дубликатом?)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, не обижусь, но не получится, потому что я уже сам пометил)))

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, оказывается, я даже читал тот ответ, но почему-то совершенно забыл.

Comment: Сам задал вопрос - сам закрыл) Таки бывает, времени-то много прошло